# Keycloak "Remember Me" Option not working

Tags: keycloak

I want to use "Remember Me" Option on the Keycloak Login Page, but for 7 days.
I made these changes from Keycloak Settings.
But it's not working and i am getting logged out after some time.

Am i missing anything?

**Screenshot from Keycloak Login Page:**
[image: Keycloak Login Page]

**Screenshot from Keycloak Settings:**

[image: Keycloak Settings]

Comment: Im currently experiencing the same issue. Any updates on this?

Comment: nope.
Still don't have any solution for this.

Comment: keycloak version? how much time after keycloak asked you for login?

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue SSO Session Idle and SSO Session Max is working properly but SSO Session Idle Remember Me and SSO Session Max Remember Me and SSO Session Max Remember Me isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

According to your configurations, your SSO Session Idle and Max timeouts are very less compare to Remember Me timeouts. Even though Remember Me expiry configurations is high, your session is getting expired after these `SSO Session Idle` or `SSO Session Max` time.

To fix this, you have to increase SSO Session Idle or SSO Session Max as per `SSO Session Idle Remember Me` or `SSO Session Max Remember Me` values.